# WIX - Passing values in command line arguments?

Tags: .net, wix

I am having a small problem with WIX - or rather, an issue with my current understanding of it.

If I have a value called, say, "MYVALUE" that I want to set via a checkbox, I already have that working fine, when I run my .msi file, the checkbox defaults to checked, this is actually the expected behavior. The main issue is when I try to bass the value on the command line, the check box is still enabled.

I have been googling around for a while, and could really use a little help here.

Answer (score 3):

Try the command:

```
msiexec /i foo.msi MYVALUE=
```

The checkbox table requires a property to be null (not set) in order to not select the checkbox.